# Reading N bytes from AWS s3 file does not read N bytes

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-java-sdk

I am trying to read N bytes from my file in AWS S3 bucket and write it into buffer, however when I try to do so, the returned amount of bytes is not N, but much much less and after multiple call it differs.

What I am doing is:

```
public int readData(byte[] data, int doff, long offset, int length, String bucketName, String fileName) throws IOException {
    GetObjectRequest rangeObjectRequest = new GetObjectRequest(bucketName, fileName)
            .withRange(offset, length);

    S3Object objectPortion = S3_CLIENT.getObject(rangeObjectRequest);

    return objectPortion.getObjectContent().read(data, doff, length);
}
```

when `offset = 0` and `length = 32752`

```
objectPortion.getObjectContent().read(data, doff, length);
```

returns `16360` while `data` size is 32820 which is enough for all data i want.

Why is this happening? Why isn't it returning all data?

The size of file i am trying to download is around 69kb

Comment: `InputStream.read()` doesn't work the way you think it does: "An attempt is made to read as many as len bytes, but a smaller number may be read". You need to read in a loop, and you'll find many similar questions on this site.

Comment: Call `read()` repeatedly, accumulating the returned data, until the value -1 is returned, indicating end of stream.

Answer (score 0):

Use this snippet to read the whole content:

```java
try (S3ObjectInputStream is = objectPortion.getObjectContent()) {
    byte[] buf = new byte[4096];
    int read = 0;

    while ((read = is.read(buf)) >= 0) {
        // use buf / read values
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    …
}
```

Comment: I did something simillar but i found out this results in infinite loop,for some reason .read() results in 0 after everything is read and you didnt read final part of the file. So some checking needs to be done.